# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module ошибка после перезагрузки сайта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\rtp.frontend\node_modules\vue-final-modal\dist\VueFinalModal.esm.js:1
import { ref, reactive, computed, watch, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount, nextTick, withScopeId, pushScopeId, popScopeId, withDirectives, openBlock, createBlock, withKeys, createVNode, Transition, mergeProps, createCommentVNode, withModifiers, renderSlot, Fragment, renderList, vShow, resolveDynamicComponent, toHandlers, createSlots, withCtx, shallowReactive } from 'vue';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:165:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25)
    at async DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:24)
    at async nodeImport (file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/rtp.frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:56019:17)
```

Проект написан на vue, vite. Проблема заключается в том, что когда сайт первый раз загружается, то все работает, когда ты находишься на странице, где используется этот модуль, перезагружаешь страницу, то происходит эта ошибка. В package-json написан type module.

Comment: Привет! Все что мне понятно, что у тебя "синтаксическая ошибка: невозможно использовать оператор импорта вне модуля", похоже что надо проверить среду выполнения или проблема в сборке, если есть дополнительная инфа пишите

Comment: привет, а что тебе показать или написать, чтобы более понятнее было? я распишу, просто скажи, что нужно

Comment: какая установлена  версия node.js ? как вариант можно переустановить заново node.js, vue.js и проверить этот код. Вроде бы для модулей нужна среда  Node.js версии от 14

Comment: node js 20 версии, самая новая. Я так понял, там проблема с ssr, потому что изначально при первой загрузке все нормально, но когда страницу перезагрузил, то появляется ошибка